# Element in div gets removed as a child but can't be used again

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a hidden table in a div then hide it again with display: none/block toggle. It works. But, I can't get it to appear again once I toggle to display: none to hide it.

HTML:
The HTML has an empty div with id = tableContainer.

Next to it, I have a table with the names of animal families in each cell, along with a button. When the button is clicked, it takes the name of the animal family from that particular cell, finds the table of animal species with that name and switches from display: none to display:block and display it /inside the div. Then, if I click the button again, it toggles the display back to display: none.

When I click a button in another cell, it clears the div and displays the new table.

All good.

But, if I click a button that was previously used, the table that has now gone is no longer available.

I have gone through all sorts of hoops playing with removeChild and all that but no luck. I am currently using innerHTML to clear the div, but I'm missing something with the class name.

Console error says: tabletest2.html:523 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at toggle (tabletest2.html:523)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (tabletest2.html:72)

So, it seems to me that it can't toggle any more because the table now no longer exists, or I may be wrong with that as I didn't delete the child element (I think).

```
     <body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Genus</td>
      <td>Benthobatis
        <button onclick="toggle(this, parentNode.firstChild)">Click me</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Genus</td>
      <td>Diplobatis
        <button onclick="toggle(this, parentNode.firstChild)">Click me</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- <======== div display container here ================>-->  
<div id="tableContainer"></div>

     <table id="Benthobatis" class="hide">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Genus</th>
        <th>Benthobatis</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Benthobatis kreffti</td>
        <td>Brazilian Blind Electric Ray</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <!-- <==================================-->
     <table id="Diplobatis" class="hide">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Genus</th>
        <th> Diplobatis </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Diplobatis colombiensis</td>
        <td>Colombian electric ray</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </body>

    <script>
function toggle(ele, tableName) {
var myTableDisplayDiv = document.getElementById("tableContainer").childNodes;
    if (myTableDisplayDiv.length != 0) {
        document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = "";
    }
        var myTableName = tableName.textContent;
        var myTable = document.getElementById(myTableName);
        myTable.classList.toggle("hide");
        document.getElementById("tableContainer").appendChild(
        document.getElementById(myTableName)        
            );
    }   

      </script>


    <style>
          .hide  {
display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Which element is `#tableContainer`? I assume one level up from `<table>`?

Comment: tableContainer is the empty div in which I put the tables. So it's html:body:tableContainer. The tables are all on the same level/hierarchy as the tableContainer, but are switched into the div on button click.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanations

> *"Why are my tables deleted if I'm only changing display option, not removing the child node?".*

This destroys everything within:

> ```
> document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = "";
> ```

This ***moves*** the chosen table to `#tableContainer`:

> ```
> document.getElementById("tableContainer").appendChild(
>     document.getElementById(myTableName)
> ```

So in three clicks there's nothing left. Of course this is if the table can be identified correctly which it wasn't. The `.textContent` of  `.parentNode.firstChild` reference was lost because `this` refers to a global context not the button. This is why on-event attributes (among other various reasons) are discouraged. Although not a critical issue as the ones previously mentioned, you should seriously have some variations to the names:

`tableName`
`myTableName`
`myTable`
`myTableDisplayDiv`
`tableContainer`

I'm pretty sure this naming scheme did not facilitate debugging.

---

### Solutions

- Before you place a table into `#tableContainer` where it gets destroyed, make a copy with `.cloneNode()`.
- Remove the `onclick` attributes and either use `onclick` property (like in the demo) or `.addEventListener()`.
- Register an ancestor element of both buttons (i.e. `tbody`), from there both buttons can be clicked and easily isolated and referenced by using `event.target`.
- Now the reference to the clicked button (`event.target`) can now be referenced:

> > ```
> > var tableName = event.target.parentNode.firstChild.textContent
> > ```

- And then the table can finally be referenced:

> > ```
> > var table = document.getElementById(tableName)
> > ```

---

### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('tbody').onclick = toggle;

function toggle(event) {

  var clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked.tagName === 'BUTTON') {

    var genus = clicked.parentNode.firstChild.textContent;

    var table = document.querySelector('#' + genus);

    var display = document.getElementById("display");

    display.innerHTML = "";

    var clone = table.cloneNode(true);

    display.appendChild(clone);

    clone.classList.toggle('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Genus</td>
      <td>Benthobatis
        <button>Click me</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Genus</td>
      <td>Diplobatis
        <button>Click me</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- <======== div display container here ================>-->
<div id="display"></div>

<table id="Benthobatis" class="hide">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Genus</th>
      <th>Benthobatis</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Benthobatis kreffti</td>
      <td>Brazilian Blind Electric Ray</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- <==================================-->
<table id="Diplobatis" class="hide">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Genus</th>
      <th> Diplobatis </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Diplobatis colombiensis</td>
      <td>Colombian electric ray</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But, that doesn't work as my page is supposed to, and avoids the burning question, "Why are my tables deleted if I'm only changing display option, not removing the child node?".

Comment: When this occurs everything within is obliterated: `document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = "";` Then `appendChild()` will ***move*** your table into that abyss and you have no logic to bring any tables back out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. And I thought ".innerHTML" was a fluffy kitten, not Tharg the Destroyer. I am very new to javascript so it's a huge learning curve. I am plodding through every line of your script and researching anything I don't understand, so your help is much appreciated. I realized that the "onclick" on the button was naughty but didn't realize that it was causing so many issues. I found today that the parent was not the td, but the wrapper div holding the whole page contents so I guess the button was going global, as you say.

Comment: Also, I liked the use of the clone, which gets destroyed, but leaves the original for another use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kind of complex to understand but if you just want to toggle the table, I think this is the best way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="table-container">
    <button class="toggle-btn">Click me</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Genus</td>
      <td>Benthobatis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Genus</td>
      <td>Diplobatis</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

  <script>
 const table = document.querySelector('table'),
       btn = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn');
       btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
         table.classList.toggle("hide")
       })
 

  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the toggle that's the problem. The toggle works, but only once. After that, the error in the console seems to suggest that the table has been deleted, when I'm only toggling display: none to display:block, not deleting the table child from the div parent.

Comment: Can you paste the whole code, because your code is not helping, for example where is `tableContainer`.